# How can I position four divs in a responsive manner?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a responsive layout with 4 blocks, like this:

```
//Box1                            Box 3




//Box 2                        Box 4
```

I want the left side (box1, box2) with 60% of width and `margin-right:5%`, and box2 with `margin-top: 5%`.

The right side (box3, box4) I want with 35% width, and box4 with `margin-top:5%`.

I'm trying to do this with percentages below, to adapt to any size, but it's not working; the elements aren't positioning where I want.

And in the h2, the background is working fine, but I want the box to have `background: white`, but it isn't working for some reason.

This is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zqmwen3n/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box-left-up">
        <h2>box 1</h2>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box-left-down">
        <h2>box 2</h2>
        <p>conteudo</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box-right-up">
        <h2>box 3</h2>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box-right-down">
        <h2>box 4</h2>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    font-family: Arial, sans;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #F9F9F9;

}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%; 
}

.box-left-up{
    background: #fff;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    margin-right:5%;
    background:#fff;

}

.box-left-up h2{
    background: #F1F1F1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    font-size:16px;
}

.box-left-up p{
    padding:10px;
}

.box-left-down{
    float:left;
    margin-top:20px;
    background: #fff;
    width:60%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.box-left-down h2{
    background: #F1F1F1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    font-size:16px;
}


.box-right-up{
    background: #fff;
    float: right;
    width:35%;
}

.box-right-up h2{
    background: #F1F1F1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    font-size:16px;
}

.box-right-down{
    background: #fff;
    float: right;
    width:35%;

}

.box-right-down h2{
    background: #F1F1F1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the 2 upper boxes in a separate container. ( Do the same for the other 2)

```css
* {
 font-family: Arial, sans;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%; 
}

.box-left-up{
 background: #fff;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    margin-right:5%;
    background:#fff;

}

.box-left-up h2{
 background: #F1F1F1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 60%;
 font-size:16px;
}

.box-left-up p{
 padding:10px;
}

.box-left-down{
 float:left;
 margin-top:20px;
 background: #fff;
    width:60%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.box-left-down h2{
 background: #F1F1F1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 60%;
 font-size:16px;
}


.box-right-up{
 background: #fff;
 float: right;
    width:35%;
}

.box-right-up h2{
 background: #F1F1F1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 60%;
 font-size:16px;
}

.box-right-down{
 background: #fff;
 float: right;
    width:35%;

}

.box-right-down h2{
 background: #F1F1F1 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 60%;
 font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <div class="box-left-up">
            <h2>box 1</h2>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
            <div class="box-right-up">
            <h2>box 3</h2>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
       <div>
        <div class="box-left-down">
            <h2>box 2</h2>
            <p>conteudo</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="box-right-down">
            <h2>box 4</h2>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4mpfu1xd/

Comment: Thank you, the boxs are in the right place now. But do you know why the background white dont works in the boxs content?

Comment: Yes. * { ... } This is applied to every tag. So P has F9F9F9 as background color. remove the background from  * and put it in body